# Открытие fig файлов

Tags: графика, веб-дизайн, поиск-программ, figma

Подскажите как можно открыть fig файл, кроме через https://www.figma.com.
Нашел в интернете - [FIG файлы](https://filext.com/ru/rasshirenie-faila/FIG), но в большинстве из приведенных ссылок не открывают fig файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри на [Lunacy](https://icons8.com/lunacy) от Icons8. Он [умеет конвертировать](https://blog.icons8.com/articles/figma-import-in-lunacy/) figma-файлы в формат sketch.

Также у figma помимо сайта [есть декстопная версия](https://www.figma.com/downloads/) редактора.